# jQuery UI radio button remaining selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm building a site with a few different jQuery UI elements and I've run into a problem.

I'm trying to use this http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio but rather than having a radio button set that toggles through like a radio select should I just get three buttons that once selected remain selected.

I'm using local copies of the jQuery UI css and js files and I have two different jQuery UIs running side by side.

I'm also using the jQuery Select2 widget http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ but removing this and using the jqueryui.com hosted versions of jQuery UI doesn't fix my problem.

Has anybody else had any similar problems? I'd post my code but the jqueryui.com example doesn't even work.

The radio buttons work fine as plain html but don't once I've added the jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: Put up your code so that we can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable a [jQuery widget button](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#option-disabled), you should use :

```
$(".button").button({ disabled: true });
```

Also open your console and see if you have errors that can cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for that mate, it turns out I had an unclosed tag further up the page that was preventing it. Apologies for wasting everyone's time.